# How to use C++ class in Windows 10 C# universal app?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I want to execute a method from cpp class in my Windows 10 C# Universal app. As i'm a newbie in Windows app development and C#, so i can use some code to understand the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:
1- Create a new Windows Universal Runtime Component DLL, using C++/CX
2- Add a new [ref class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699870.aspx) to it. This class will be a wrapper to your C++ code.
3- Call your C++ method from that new class
4- Add a reference to the new DLL from your C# project, and use the C++/CX wrapper class from there.

Comment: Good, but seems incomplete: I see no mention of any goat sacrifice to the gods of managed non-managed code interop.

Comment: @Yakk fair enough, however there was no information at all in the question about the nature of the C++ method that the OP intents to call.